# How to deserialize a blank JSON string value to null for java.lang.String?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying a simple JSON to de-serialize in to java object. I am however, getting empty *String* values for `java.lang.String` property values. In rest of the properties, blank values are converting to *null* values(which is what I want).

My JSON and related Java class are listed below.

JSON string:

```json
{
  "eventId" : 1,
  "title" : "sample event",
  "location" : "" 
}
```

*EventBean* class POJO:

```java
public class EventBean {

    public Long eventId;
    public String title;
    public String location;

}
```

My main class code:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);

try {
    File file = new   File(JsonTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("event.txt").getFile());

    JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(file);
    // find out the applicationId

    EventBean e = mapper.treeToValue(root, EventBean.class);
    System.out.println("It is " + e.location);
}
```

I was expecting print "It is null". Instead, I am getting "It is ". Obviously, *Jackson* is not treating blank String values as NULL while converting to my *String* object type.

I read somewhere that it is expected. However, this is something I want to avoid for *java.lang.String* too. Is there a simple way?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Jackson will give you null for other objects, but for String it will give empty String.

But you can use a Custom `JsonDeserializer` to do this:

```
class CustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();
        if (node.asText().isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return node.toString();
    }

}
```

In class you have to use it for location field:

```
class EventBean {
    public Long eventId;
    public String title;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
    public String location;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me too, but using readValueAsTree() wrapped the string in extra quotes. So to avoid it I used instead jsonParser.readValueAs(String.class);

Comment: @kopelitsa extra quotes issue could be resolved by "return node.asText();"

Comment: Can we apply the JsonDeserialize annotation to class level also , so that all the string attributes with empty string under that will convert to null ?

Comment: @AnsarSamad Did you have an answer to your question? I would need to understand if it can be inserted at the class level

Comment: @Jacket yes it also works on the class level for all String fields.

Comment: @kopelitsa yes this works, but only if this deserializer is never globally registered as a String deserializer via modules (see other answers below). Then you would end up with an infinite loop, so beware.

Comment: @SachinGupta your code contains a small error; the final return statement should also use `node.asText()` so you don't return the double quotes. Please update your answer, i've tried to improve it with an edit but the reviewers rejected it.

Answer (score 23):

It is possible to define a custom deserializer for the String type, overriding the standard String deserializer:

```
this.mapper = new ObjectMapper();

SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();

module.addDeserializer(String.class, new StdDeserializer<String>(String.class) {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String result = StringDeserializer.instance.deserialize(p, ctxt);
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(result)) {
            return null;
        }
        return result;
    }
});

mapper.registerModule(module);
```

This way all String fields will behave the same way.

Answer (score 10):

You might first like to see if there has been any progress on [the Github issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/768) requesting this exact feature.

For those using Spring Boot: The answer from jgesser was the most helpful to me, but I spent a while trying to work out the best way to configure it in Spring Boot.

Actually, [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) says:

> Any beans of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module are
>   automatically registered with the auto-configured
>   Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder and are applied to any ObjectMapper
>   instances that it creates.

So here's jgesser's answer expanded into something you can copy-paste into a new class in a Spring Boot application

```
@Configuration
public class EmptyStringAsNullJacksonConfiguration {

  @Bean
  SimpleModule emptyStringAsNullModule() {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();

    module.addDeserializer(
        String.class,
        new StdDeserializer<String>(String.class) {

          @Override
          public String deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context)
              throws IOException {
            String result = StringDeserializer.instance.deserialize(parser, context);
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(result)) {
              return null;
            }
            return result;
          }
        });

    return module;
  }
}
```

Comment: Alas, the issue you're referring to has been closed by (one of) the maintainer(s) due to seemingly apparent lack of interest...

Answer (score 4):

I could get this by following configuration.

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
```

Comment: This doesn't work - that deserialization feature is intended just for empty strings as the whole JSON expression (indicated by that "NULL_OBJECT") - not for object attributes.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to use JsonCreator annotation. It worked for me

```
public class Foo {
private String field;

 @JsonCreator
 public Foo(
   @JsonProrerty("field") String field) {
     this.field = StringUtils.EMPTY.equals(field) ? null : field ;
}
}
```